# Converting Kinect depth to png (python)

Tags: python, png, point-cloud-library, depth

I try to verify a segmenting algorithm and therefore i need some good data. I want to use the NYU Depth V2 dataset (http://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html). Now i want to create some pcd-data, with the point-cloud-library png2pcd method. But I need a color- and a depth-image. The colored one is no problem, but the depth is saved as float in meter. So basically values like these:

[[ 2.75201321  2.75206947  2.75221062 ...

Is there a possibility to save those values in a png-file, without scaling them in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible to store floating point values in a PNG. The highest resolution data you can store in a PNG is a 16-bit unsigned integer per sample, in the range 0..65535.

If you want to store floating point distances you need to look to:

- TIFF, which can store 32 and 64-bit floats, or
- PFM which can store 32-bit floats, or
- OpenEXR which can store 32-bit floats

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about extracting NYUv2 subset of 1449 labeled dataset, the following conversion will work. I am not sure for raw depth values since I am also having similar issue but my depth value ranges from 0-2047. Do you know some way to save this in .png format?

```
    for i, (image, depth) in enumerate(zip(f['images'], f['depths'])):
    print("SHAPE::", np.shape(image), np.shape(depth), np.max(depth),np.min(depth))
    ra_image = image.transpose(2, 1, 0)
    ra_depth = depth.transpose(1, 0)
    re_depth = (ra_depth/np.max(ra_depth))*255.0
    print("AFTER--", np.shape(image), np.shape(depth), np.max(re_depth), np.min(re_depth))
    image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(ra_image))
    depth_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(re_depth))
    image_name = os.path.join("data", "nyu_datasets", "%05d.jpg" % (i))
    # image_pil.save(image_name)
    depth_name = os.path.join("data", "nyu_datasets", "%05d.png" % (i))
    # depth_pil.save(depth_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In OpenCV python:

```
depthMap = numpy.array([your depth value array])
cv2.imwrite('xxx.png', depthMap)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot store floating point data in a PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible! The PNG-Format is able to save 16 Bit per pixel for One-Channel pictures. You can save the depth information in meters with integer.

```
depth_image_as_array = np.assaray(depth_image, dtype=float16)
depth_image_as_array = depth_image_as_array * 1000
depth_image = Image.fromarray(depth_image_as_array)
depth_image.save("depth_image.png")
```

Comment: This is incorrect, on 2 counts. Firstly, PNG is compressed and secondly it cannot store floating point data.

Comment: Hey Mark, sorry for the wrong answer you are right. I didn't test the saved image. In my opinion is the only option to calculate meters to millimeters an save the depth information into png.